# Why was the body needed in Lucky Number Slevin?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucky-number-slevin

[Lucky Number Slevin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425210/) is a fantastic genre bending movie with a strange blend of thriller-crime-humour. And it has an excellent twist which I won't reveal for those who have not seen it (but it is the sort of movie that repays multiple viewings even though you know the twist second time around).

One part of the movie requires the protagonist to procure a body for use in a "kansas city shuffle". The reason for the need for a body is explained but the events that transpire (planned by the protagonist and his associate) render the given explanation somewhat redundant. So for what possible reason did they actually need the body given their actions negate the explanation they gave to the other characters?

Comment: Every reviewing you can detect just another differently patterned wallpaper, tie, or bedsheet.

Answer (score 13):

The body belongs to the *actual* Nick Fisher, who is being killed by Goodcat in the beginning of the movie. He is being chosen because Slevin and Goodcat need someone who has a large monetary debt with both gangster bosses (The Rabbi and The Boss).

This way when Slevin takes Nick Fisher's place in his apartment, he will get mistaken for Fisher and be able to get close to the two unsuspecting bosses. This enables him to fulfill his plan to kill those two men who killed his father.

The body of Nick Fisher however is needed by Slevin to fake his own death and dissapear after his plan has succeeded. Before they blow up The Fairy's apartment, they put the body there so the police will later find out that Nick Fisher died in the incident and probably will close the file, leaving no questions open and no links to Slevin.

Comment: But why does Slevin need to do that given that the police probably have no idea who he is (after all he has already been dead a couple of decades)?

Comment: Why did he do what? Kill Nick Fisher? Or place the body?

Comment: He killed Nick Fisher because he needed him out of the way to take his spot. And he placed the body so nobody would be looking for the missing Fisher once Slevin dissapeared. Especially since he draw attention to himself, it was just the better solution. If he did not place the body, people would be looking for him and they knew what he looked like.

Comment: Closing the file, as well for the police and the ones maybe looking for revenge is the main aim I guess. You can't kill someone already dead.

Comment: Didn't Slevin kill the cop after blowing up the body of Nick Fisher? How would he expect the case to close then?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I thought I'd throw in on account of the unanswered question...to make their plan work, they need to kill someone for a body. But in killing this man who may have had a family as well, they are stooping to the level that the leaders of the gangs did when they killed Slevin's father.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and it isn't strictly accurate even as a comment as Nick Fisher didn't have a family and did have a conviction for child molestation which hardly paints him as a good guy.

Answer (score 0):

Nick Fisher's death was really uncalled for. Slevin didn't need his body to fake his death because for one, Slevin obviously didn't reside there. He could've easily left after the job was finished. Two, he was using a pseudonym the whole movie. No one knew his true identity. There were other ways to fulfill their plan without killing Nick Fisher.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.